# Cassandra Multiple Prepared Statements for Nullable Columns

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

Because of infrastructure restrictions, we cannot upgrade the version of Cassandra running to > 2.2, so we have to use 2.0.7. This version unfortunately does not support the use of `UNSET`. As the data we're writing has nullable columns, to my knowledge, we can either create our own notion of `null` (ie. empty string, empty data structure), or create multiple PreparedStatements (the same query, but ignoring the field that would contain a `null` value as we do not want to bind `null` to a Prepared Statement).

Cassandra is now throwing a `13:13:28.679 [cluster1-worker-5] WARN  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Re-preparing already prepared query. Please note that preparing the same query more than once is generally an anti-pattern and will likely affect performance. Consider preparing the statement only once.`

What's the best workaround in this scenario? Most guides are telling us to simply use `UNSET` :(.

Comment: This is not error, it's warning it's because of you are preparing same query multiple times

Comment: The work arounds in this article might help
http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/09/15/Null-bindings-on-prepared-statements-and-undesired-tombstone-creation.html

Answer (score 0):

Create `ENUM` that contains default values for each column.

Create getter method that will return the default value if is `NULL`.

Assign Default value for Nullable properties as part of data validation before you query to Cassandra.

If you need more help, add your relevant schema.

Comment: So you're essentially suggesting to store our own representation of null in the DB right? Isn't that a waste of space though? It looks like `UNSET` in Cassandra v2.2 or later sets `bytebuffer.allocate(0)` (https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.java#L145), but there isn't a public function in v2.0 that allows you set it externally

Comment: I suggest you to handle `unset` in application by declaring defaults values in your application.